# About the conjugates of an element

Tags: commutative-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Assume we have two field extension $K \subset L $ and $ K \subset M$ assume the last one is Galois.
Fix $x\in L$ an algebraic element and $ a \in M$, denote $a_1,\dots ,a_n$ the conjugates of a.
Is it true that all the conjugates of $a-x$ over $L$ are $a_1-x,\dots,a_n-x$?

Comment: No. Consider the case of $K=\Bbb{Q}$, $a=x=\sqrt2$. May be you have left out an assumption?